# Как переместить значения utm параметров URL'а внутрь атрибута href в дополнение к ссылке?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Пользователь переходит по объявлению, которое содержит utm метки. Когда он зашел на сайт, то у него по идее значения добавляются к utm меткам

Выходит, что в url строке браузера, условно,

```
domain.com/?utm_term={keyword}&utm_creative={creative}&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_position={adposition}
```

Заменяется на

```
domain.com/?utm_term=asdf&utm_creative=1321&utm_campaign=31&utm_position=dfgdfg
```

Как теперь можно вытащить значения определенных utm'ок и сформировать другую ссылку в теге `<a>` вида

```
<a href=site.com/?camp=31&keyword=asdf&creative=1321&position=dfgdfg
```

с php и js почти не знаком, но сейчас внезапно понадобилось сделать такое

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `location.search`, если текущая страница

```
domain.com/?utm_term=asdf&utm_creative=1321&utm_campaign=31&utm_position=dfgdfg
```

Чтобы получить ссылку с такими же параметрами на другой сайт

```
const otherDomain = 'otherDomain.com/' + location.search
// otherDomain.com/?utm_term=asdf&utm_creative=1321&utm_campaign=31&utm_position=dfgdfg
```